# pandas: merge (join) two data frames on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, pandas-merge

I am trying to join two pandas dataframes using two columns:

```py
new_df = pd.merge(A_df, B_df,  how='left', left_on='[A_c1,c2]', right_on = '[B_c1,c2]')
```

but got the following error:

```
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4164)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4028)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13166)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13120)()

KeyError: '[B_1, c2]'
```

Any idea what should be the right way to do this?

Comment: `left_on` and `right_on` should be a list of strings, not a string that looks like a list.

Answer (score 614, accepted):

Try this

```
new_df = pd.merge(A_df, B_df,  how='left', left_on=['A_c1','c2'], right_on = ['B_c1','c2'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

> left_on : label or list, or array-like Field names to join on in left
> DataFrame. Can be a vector or list of vectors of the length of the
> DataFrame to use a particular vector as the join key instead of
> columns
>
> right_on : label or list, or array-like Field names to join on
> in right DataFrame or vector/list of vectors per left_on docs

Answer (score 23):

1. It merges according to the ordering of `left_on` and `right_on`, i.e., the i-th element of `left_on` will match with the i-th of `right_on`.

   In the example below, the code on the top matches `A_col1` with `B_col1` and `A_col2` with `B_col2`, while the code on the bottom matches `A_col1` with `B_col2` and `A_col2` with `B_col1`. Evidently, the results are different.

   [image: res1]
2. As can be seen from the above example, if the merge keys have different names, all keys will show up as their individual columns in the merged dataframe. In the example above, in the top dataframe, `A_col1` and `B_col1` are identical and `A_col2` and `B_col2` are identical. In the bottom dataframe, `A_col1` and `B_col2` are identical and `A_col2` and `B_col1` are identical. Since these are duplicate columns, they are most likely not needed. One way to not have this problem from the beginning is to make the merge keys identical from the beginning. See bullet point #3 below.
3. If `left_on` and `right_on` are the same `col1` and `col2`, we can use `on=['col1', 'col2']`. In this case, no merge keys are duplicated.

   ```py
   df1.merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2'])
   ```

   [image: res3]
4. You can also merge one side on column names and the other side on index too. For example, in the example below, `df1`'s columns are matched with `df2`'s indices. If the indices are named, as in the example below, you can reference them by name but if not, you can also use `right_index=True` (or `left_index=True` if the left dataframe is the one being merged on index).

   ```py
   df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A_col1', 'A_col2'], right_index=True)
   # or
   df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A_col1', 'A_col2'], right_on=['B_col1', 'B_col2'])
   ```

   [image: res3]
5. By using the `how=` parameter, you can perform `LEFT JOIN` (`how='left'`), `FULL OUTER JOIN` (`how='outer'`) and `RIGHT JOIN` (`how='right'`) as well. The default is `INNER JOIN` (`how='inner'`) as in the examples above.
6. If you have more than 2 dataframes to merge and the merge keys are the same across all of them, then `join` method is more efficient than `merge` because you can pass a list of dataframes and join on indices. Note that the index names are the same across all dataframes in the example below (`col1` and `col2`). Note that the indices don't have to have names; if the indices don't have names, then the number of the multi-indices must match (in the case below there are 2 multi-indices). Again, as in bullet point #1, the match occurs according to the ordering of the indices.

   ```py
   df1.join([df2, df3], how='inner').reset_index()
   ```

   [image: res4]

Answer (score 15):

Another way of doing this:

```
new_df = A_df.merge(B_df, left_on=['A_c1','c2'], right_on = ['B_c1','c2'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 13):

the problem here is that by using the apostrophes you are setting the value being passed to be a string, when in fact, as @Shijo stated from the documentation, the function is expecting a label or list, but not a string! If the list contains each of the name of the columns beings passed for both the left and right dataframe, then each column-name *must* individually be within apostrophes. With what has been stated, we can understand why this is inccorect:

```
new_df = pd.merge(A_df, B_df,  how='left', left_on='[A_c1,c2]', right_on = '[B_c1,c2]')
```

And this is the correct way of using the function:

```
new_df = pd.merge(A_df, B_df,  how='left', left_on=['A_c1','c2'], right_on = ['B_c1','c2'])
```

Answer (score 13):

you can use below which is short and simple to understand:

```
merged_data= df1.merge(df2, on=["column1","column2"])
```

Answer (score -1):

this work for me , for n files xls

```py
# all_reports_paths contain one array with all paths per files
for a in all_reports_paths:
    
    df.append( pd.read_excel(a,skiprows=X,skipfooter=X))

df_glob = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for dataframe in df:

    df_glob = pd.concat([df_glob,pd.DataFrame(dataframe)],axis=0)

# finally df_glob contain all data
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).