# Combine 2 different dataframes and getting only the same data

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to combine 2 dataframes and create another dataframe with combined values that have the id in common.

DF1:

```
id    country   age

123    US       30

234    MY       45

432    AF       32
```

DF2:

```
id   country   name

123    US      Bill

234    MY      Luis

432    AF      Joe

787    SG      Mark
```

How do I combine these two df and get only the data with same 'id'.

What i want:

DF3:

```
id    country   age   name 

123    US       30    Bill

234    MY       45    Luis

432    AF       32    Joe
```

Comment: Please format the dataframe properly. It's hard to look at.

Comment: @NaumanNaeem, sorry I would if I knew how. I'll try to change it when I get the chance thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Join pandas dataframes based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781633/join-pandas-dataframes-based-on-column-values).

You can do

```py
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id','country'], how='left')
```

Comment: I tried this on my data, I have about 2500 on one df and about 10,000 on the other df. I was supposed to get 2500 or lower but I got about 9000 for the merged df.

Comment: Basically I used your suggestion and added: `df3.drop_duplicates(subset ="id", keep = "first", inplace = True) ` and got the results I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Check my edit, you can use the left join. [Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)