# Join a dataframe with a column from another, based on a common column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark dataframes:

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
| 21  | 999 | 1000|
| 22  | 786 | 1978|
| 23  | 345 | 1563|
```

and

```
|  A  |  D  |  E  |
| 21  | aaa | a12 |
| 22  | bbb | b43 |
| 23  | ccc | h67 |
```

Desired result:

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  E  |
| 21  | 999 | 1000| a12 |
| 22  | 786 | 1978| b43 |
| 23  | 345 | 1563| h67 |
```

I tried using join, even `df1.join(df2.E, df1.A == df2.A)` to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: merge (join) two data frames on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: `df1.join(df2, "A").select("A", "B", "C", "E")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code does what you want:

```
joinedDF = df1.join(df2.select('A', 'E'), ['A'])
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to join the 2 dataframe using the function `join` it takes 3 arguments.

1. arg-1 : another dataframe which you need to join.
2. arg-2 : columns based on which you need to join the dataframes.
3. arg-3 : Type of join you want to perform. by default its inner join.

PFB sample code.

```
df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id, 'outer')
```

You can find more details [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join).

Regards,

Neeraj