# How can I select an input from a column if it meets multiple conditions from different columns in a different row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select certain inputs that match my conditions of other columns and create a new column with that value.

I have tried `.merge`, `.loc` `ifelse` and I continue to have something wrong.

I have a dataframe with tickers as the index and the following columns for multiple stocks and option data `['date', 'price', 'exdate', 'position']`

If the condition is met of having a '1' in the position column, I want to look in the table and obtain the 'price' on the 'date' that would be equal to the 'exdate' and display it in a new column to the right. The price should be in the same price as the 1. Short example:

```
import numpy as np                                  
import pandas as pd 

t = pd.DataFrame(index=['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN'])
t['Date']     = ['12/01/2017','12/02/2017','12/03/2017','12/04/2017','12/01/2017','12/02/2017','12/03/2017','12/04/2017']
t['Price']    = [125.5, 123.1, 126.4, 128.9, 431.2, 433.5, 432.6, 444.0]
t['Exdate']   = ['12/04/2017','12/04/2017','12/04/2017','12/04/2017','12/04/2017','12/04/2017','12/04/2017','12/04/2017']
t['Position'] = [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
t
```

Comment: an example of data and output would be very helpful

Comment: agree, just uploaded a quick example

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to merge on two conditions, one of which is index match and another date vs exdate match. It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079), but back then (0.19) Pandas didn't support mixed index/column conditions. Now (0.24) it does, but the index should have a name. So, here is an example:

```
t.index.name = 'name'
t.loc[t['Position'].astype(bool)].merge(
    t[['Date', 'Price']], left_on=['name', 'Exdate'], right_on=['name', 'Date'])
```

Output

```
          Date_x  Price_x      Exdate  Position      Date_y  Price_y
name                                                                
AAPL  12/01/2017    125.5  12/04/2017         1  12/04/2017    128.9
AMZN  12/03/2017    432.6  12/04/2017         1  12/04/2017    444.0
```

From the question I'm not sure what should be done with records where Position is 0, but I hope you can figure it out the same way.

Comment: Thanks @Marat. I just tried this and I am getting the same table as before, no difference. Any thoughts?  `table.index.name = 'ticker'
table.loc[table['position'].astype(bool)].merge(table[['date', 'price']], left_on=['ticker', 'exdate'], right_on=['ticker', 'date'])`

Comment: I think there is something missing in the code to look for 'position' == 1

Comment: 1) what is your pandas version? This feature was introduced not so long ago. 2) converting to bool is equivalent to `== 1`

Comment: and additional question to modify the data, how can I include the rows where position is 0 as you mentioned above? So I don't discard that info which might help me for further calculations

Comment: it depends on what you wanto to do with these rows. Trivially, you can just skip the `.loc[t['Position'].astype(bool)]` part, but I'm not sure how useful will be the result