# Dataframe: Join dataframe with explicitly define join columns

Tags: python, databricks

suppose I have two dataframe
df1 : col1 col2 col3
df2 : col1 col2 col4

I would like to join two dataframe using col1 and col2 without defining a new alias table name.

I don't want to do

df=df1.join(df2,(df1.col1 == df2.col1) & (df1.col2 == df2.col2)   << this is so dummy 
And also remove the duplicated join columns after join .

so the final dataframe will have col1 col2 col3 col4 only

How to achieve that ?

Comment: This link might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Please provide sample datas for dataframes and expected output

Comment: acutally I am not using panda, I am using spark dataframe...
can I do it in spark dataframe ?

Comment: anyone has more idea ?

Answer (score 0):

for spark dataframe, use like below.

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, ['col1', 'col2'])
df3.show()
```

Comment: are there any way to do from an array ??

Comment: like   c for c in arraycols

Comment: it should work for arrays too. Please post the code, if it is not working.

Comment: what's the syntax ??
df1.join(df2, (c for c in colsarray))

Comment: What do you mean by `colsarray`?

Comment: colsarray=['col1','col2','col3']

Comment: `df3 = df1.join(df2, colsarray)` use like these.

Comment: how to deal with there are null values in the columns when doing join ?

Comment: anyone with idea how to deal with Null values when using the join method above ? coz when there is null values, there is no join