# Merge a dataframe only when the column values are identical

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df` and `df_copy`. I would like to copy the data from `df_copy`, but only if the data is also identical. How do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Nameid': [100, 200, 300, 100]
     , 'Name': ['Max', 'Michael', 'Susan', 'Max']
     , 'Projectid': [100, 200, 200, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head(5))

df['nameid_index'] = df['Nameid'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['projectid_index'] = df['Projectid'].astype('category').cat.codes
display(df.head(5))

df_copy = df.copy()

df.drop(['Nameid', 'Name', 'Projectid'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.drop([1, 3])
display(df.head(5))
```

df

[image]

df_copy

[image]

What I want

[image]

---

I looked at [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

```
df.merge(df_copy, on=['nameid_index', 'projectid_index'])
```

But I got this result

[image]

The same row are twice, I only want once.

Comment: So need `df.drop_duplicates(['nameid_index', 'projectid_index']).merge(df_copy, on=['nameid_index', 'projectid_index'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael thank you very much! Didn't know that I combine this. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: merge (join) two data frames on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['nameid_index', 'projectid_index'])
         .merge(df_copy, on=['nameid_index', 'projectid_index']))
```

If need merge by intersection of columns names in both `DataFrame`s, `on` parameter should be removed:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['nameid_index', 'projectid_index']).merge(df_copy)
```