# Joining two pandas dataframes and finding the subsequent value after the merge

Tags: pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, like so:

**Table A:**

| Country | Item | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | Croissant | 2020-03-01 |
| England | Scone | 2020-04-03 |
| France | Croissant | 2020-05-01 |
| England | Scone | 2020-06-03 |

**Table B:**

| Country | Item | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | Croissant | 2020-05-02 |
| England | Scone | 2020-06-04 |
| France | Croissant | 2020-03-02 |
| England | Scone | 2020-04-05 |

I'd like to join these two tables together so that for each country-item pairing and unique start date, the subsequent end date is appended.  Like so:

| Country | Item | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | Croissant | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-02 |
| England | Scone | 2020-04-03 | 2020-04-04 |
| France | Croissant | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-02 |
| England | Scone | 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-04 |

Right now, I'm doing the following:

1. Left join of the end date data onto the start date data
2. Group by the start date and collecting the end dates into a sorted list
3. Finding the date within this list that is the closest subsequent date after the start date

I feel like there's got to be a better way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: merge (join) two data frames on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: No, I'm able to join on multiple columns.  I guess I'm just wondering if there's a way to join  using some other condition besides "=".  So that the dates correspond to each other as shown above without me having to do the left join first and then filter.