# One-one mapping of two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

- I have two tables `Order` and `Product`.
- Both tables have one `ID` field, 3 `feature` fields, and one `Date` field.
- I want to create an output table that can help me map from the `Order` table to the `Product` table.
  The conditions to satisfy are:

  - The order should match all the 3 features with the Product and should be a one-one mapping.
  - The `Delivery Date` of the `Product` should be before the `Order` date.
  - The product-order combination should be unique. For 2 orders with the same combination of features, they will get assigned to the product which has the earliest delivery date. Ideally, the first order should get the first delivered product, and the second-order should get the second delivered product if they have the same set of features.

Please see the screenshots for an example:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHti8.png)
I tried using `left join` but I am getting one order mapped to multiple products.

I need to have the one-one mapping of an order to a single product in such a way that the `delivery date` is before the `order date`.

Please advise how to write code in Python.

```
import pandas as pd

order = pd.DataFrame({'order_id': [1,2,3,4,5], 
                       'Feature 1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B'],
                       'Feature 2': ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E','E'],
                       'Feature 3': ['G', 'G', 'H', 'H','H'],
                       'Delivery Date': ['01-Feb-2021','02-Apr-2021','03-May-2021','04-Jun-2021','05-Jun-2021']
                      })

product = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 
                       'Feature 1': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','B','B','B','B'],
                       'Feature 2': ['D','E','E','D','E','D','E','D','E','D','E','E'],
                       'Feature 3': ['G','H','G','G','G','H','H','G','H','H','H','H'],
                       'Delivery Date': ['15-Feb-2021','16-Feb-2021','17-Feb-2021','18-Feb-2021','19-Feb-2021','20-Jun-2021',
                                      '21-Jul-2021','01-Jan-2021','21-Feb-2021','20-Feb-2021','10-Feb-2021','21-Jul-2021']
                      })
```

Comment: You should use inner join. `df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='a')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: merge (join) two data frames on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Hi @irfanuddin, inner or left join will given multiple combinations as output. 
new_df = pd.merge(order, product,  how='left', left_on=['Feature_1','Feature_2','Feature_3'], right_on =['Feature_1','Feature_2','Feature_3']), new_df1 = pd.merge(order, product,  how='inner',on= ['Feature_1','Feature_2','Feature_3']). For example. Order 1 gets assigned with both Product 1 and 8. Ideally, it should only be assigned with 8 since product 8 has the earliest delivery date. Also, product 8 should no longer be available to match for the remaining orders in the list.

Comment: I get it, I probably can write a piece of code in the morning :)