# Search and update values in other dataframe for specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframe in pandas.

## First

| A | B | C | D | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 |
| **1** | **5** | 3 | 2 | **0** |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 0 |

## Second

| A | B | C | D | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| **1** | **5** | 4 | 3 | **1** |

I want column values A and B in the first dataframe to be searched in the second dataframe. If A and B values match then update the Value column.Search only 2 columns in other dataframe and update only 1 column. Actually the process we know in sql.

## Result

| A | B | C | D | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 |
| **1** | **5** | 3 | 2 | **1** |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 0 |

If you focus on the bold text, you can understand it more easily.Despite my attempts, I could not succeed. I only want 1 column to change but it also changes A and B. I only want the Value column of matches to change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: merge (join) two data frames on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: No because its change other A and B values too. Its creating duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `merge`:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
df1['VALUE'] = (df2.merge(df1[cols], on=cols, how='right')
                ['Value'].fillna(df1['VALUE'], downcast='infer')
               )
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  D  VALUE
0  1  2  3  5      0
1  1  5  3  2      1
2  2  5  3  2      0
```