# How to join in pandas one to many?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two tables. First table is df_1, down below:

| job_function | job_area | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| General Management | Human Resources | manager |
| Learning / Training | IT / Computers / Electronics | personnel |

And second table is df_2, down below:

| job_function | job_area | id | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| General Management | Human Resources | 12312312 | manager |
| Learning / Training | IT / Computers / Electronics | 12312237 | personnel |
| General Management | Human Resources | 12312315 | manager |
| Learning / Training | IT / Computers / Electronics | 12312234 | personnel |

I want to merge df_2 with df_1, however as you can see there is one to many relationship. So if joining job_function, job_area, title on df_1, in df_2 you will have many ids which will have the same job_function, job_area, title

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Why would you want to merge both dataframes if all columns of df_1 are already part of df_2?

Comment: @IgnacioHernández Sorry if it was not too clear, basically it only looks like this in example, however not all column from df_2 in df_1. And my main goal, is to have id from df_2 in df_1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do (both CSVs I use are identical to what you have in your question):

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_csv('document1.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('document2.csv')

key_cols = ['job_function', 'job_area', 'title']
merged_df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2,  how='left', left_on=key_cols, right_on=key_cols)
```

Source: [How to join two dataframes on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815079/pandas-merge-join-two-data-frames-on-multiple-columns)